# Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed despite matching datatypes

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I have data in MariaDB and am trying to run an ALTER TABLE:

`` ALTER TABLE `readings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`SiteID`) REFERENCES station(`SiteID`); ``

Both tables are already populated and I have made sure the data types are the same. However I keep getting this error saying that the foreign key constraints are incorrectly formed.

Not sure what else I could be getting wrong. I did also run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS but that returns an empty set.

Table Descriptions:

```
DESCRIBE readings;

ReadingID       bigint(20)  NO  PRI     NULL        
Date Time       datetime    YES         NULL        
NOx             double      YES         NULL        
NO2             double      YES         NULL        
NO              double      YES         NULL        
PM10            double      YES         NULL        
VPM10           double      YES         NULL        
VPM10           double      YES         NULL        
NVPM2.5         double      YES         NULL        
PM2.5           double      YES         NULL        
VPM2.5          double      YES         NULL        
CO              double      YES         NULL    
O3              double      YES         NULL        
SO2             double      YES         NULL        
Temperature     double      YES         NULL        
RH              double      YES         NULL        
Air Pressure    double      YES         NULL
DateStart       datetime    YES         NULL        
DateEnd         datetime    YES         NULL        
Current         tinyint(1)  YES         NULL        
Instrument Type text        YES         NULL        
SiteID          bigint(20)  YES         NULL
```

---

```
DESCRIBE stations;

SiteID          bigint(20)  NO  PRI     NULL        
Location        text        YES         NULL        
geo_point_2d    text        YES         NULL
```

Comment: Would you mind posting both tables' description? Not as a comment - edit the original question.

Comment: @Littlefoot sorry I'm running DESCRIBE `tablename` and trying to copy into the original question but it wont keep the formatting so becomes difficult to read. Do you know another way for me to provide that information?

Comment: Post it as you can, we'll reformat it if necessary.

Comment: @Littlefoot done, thanks

Comment: Well, you described table **stations**, while ALTER TABLE references table **station**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you reference a non-existing table in your statement (`station` instead of `stations`).

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `readings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`SiteID`) REFERENCES stations(`SiteID`);
```

Unfortunately, MariaDB gives you this error message instead of telling you that you try to reference the wrong table.